# Can selecting UICollectionViewCell and getting indexPath be done by this way?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having a scenario in which I need to get the `indexpath` of selected cell & have the contents of an array at that particular index number of a collection view. I can do that by various ways. But I wonder that if there is an equivalent code for collection view as I have did for table view in the following code -

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "segueupdate"
    {

       let update = segue.destinationViewController as! EnterDetailViewController


        let indexpath = self.tableview .indexPathForSelectedRow

        let row = indexpath?.row

        print(people[row!])//here it prints the value at particular index of the array




               }
}
```

The advantage of this method I feel is that I don't need to write the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()`. So Can I do something like this for collection view in which I need not write the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath()` ? My Code so far with error commented at the particular line -

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

                let indexPath = self.myCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
                let selectedIndexPath = indexPath?.first
                print(selectedIndexPath)
                print( people.objectAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!) //Here I get an error as value of [NSIndexPath] has no member row?      
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indexPathsForSelectedItems which will return an NSArray of NSIndexPath objects or nil depending on what has been selected in your collectionView.

To fix what you have tried do this

```
    let selectedIndexPaths = self.myCollectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPaths?.first
    print(selectedIndexPath)
    print(people[(selectedIndexPath?.row)!])
```

However if you just want to print something from your array for the selected cell I would do

```
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    print(people[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: Ya I know that but please give an equivalent code to the above code ,as I am unable to achiwvw the same.

Comment: Try to write it yourself and if you have trouble post a question with what you have tried so far. It will be similar to your tableView example, except you will need to write a bit of code to handle an array of indexPaths being passed back instead of a single indexPath object.

Comment: Okay please check I have edited my question with some of my code.

Comment: Sorry,I had posted a wrong code.Please check my code once again.